# Which are my mains?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I'm installing a Sense energy monitor and am trying to figure out which are my mains.

This photo is of my main panel, but there's a sub-panel in our house as well, which I'm assuming a couple of these go to.

Are the primary mains the ones with the yellow "caps" on them?

[image]

Comment: Three wire through PVC? (Scratching head)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the wires behind the yellow are the supply for this panel. You can see that they're attached directly to the main disconnect/breaker.

The smaller wires exiting the bottom are connected to a breaker on the bus, indicating that they're feeders for a sub-panel.

Answer (score 1):

The mains are the large breaker at the bottom.
The sub panel is fed from the 2 pole breaker near the top right, with the large wires on it.